# Java Swing: How to check what components are opened at runtime?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am using Java Swing and having the following question:

Is there a way to see what kind of top level containers are opened by the user at runtime?

There is a button on my UI, which opens a `JFrame` and since it can not be made modal the user can open an endless amount of frames. I want to prevent the user from doing that. (Just in case: I don't want to switch to a `JDialog` :) )

Comment: *"(just in case: I dont want to switch to a JDialog :) )"* .. Why?

Comment: Because it would take to much time to switch. When I programmed the UI I didnt thought about that problem.

Comment: *"Because it would take to much time to switch."* It'll take more time to get (basically working) code & considerably more time in maintenance, to persist with the current approach. Make the change to `JDialog` now in order to save time in the long run.

Comment: You would be right if that was a piece of professional work. This is just a small tool for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static method [`Window.getWindows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--).

> Returns an array of all `Window`s, both owned and ownerless,
>     created by this application.

Thus you will get all frames and dialogs.

May be you need to trim down this array by [`isShowing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isShowing--)
to skip the currently closed windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas!

```
                Window[] openedWindows = Window.getWindows();
                int countOfShowingWindows = 0;
                for (Window window : openedWindows)
                {
                    if (window.isShowing()) ++countOfShowingWindows;
                }
                if (countOfShowingWindows == 1)
                {
                    // Open the Dialog
                }
```